# css selector for multiple ng-view in a html page

Tags: html, css, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I'm trying to get css path of a textbox in a Web page which has multiple `<ng-view>` tags and classes with the same name as given below :

```
<body class="learn-bar ng-scope" ng-app="todomvc">
  <aside class="learn">
    <ng-view class="ng-scope">
      <section id="todoapp" class="ng-scope">
         <header id="header">
            <h1>todos</h1>
            <form id="todo-form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-submit="addTodo()">
                 <input id="new-todo" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Intended web element for which css path is needed" ng-model="newTodo" ng-disabled="saving" autofocus=""/>
           </form>
        </header >
```

Firebug extension on Mozilla provided CSSselector as:

```
html body.learn-bar.ng-scope ng-view.ng-scope section#todoapp.ng-scope header#header form#todo-form.ng-pristine.ng-valid input#new-todo.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched
```

Which doesn't seem to work when I do:

```
// node.js + selenium webdriver bindings
driver.findElement(By.css("<above css path>")).sendKeys("value");
```

It gives error:

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector": }

How do I bypass these `ng-view` tags and locate appropriate webelement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `relative` path instead of `absolute` one.

If you have element id Then better approach to locate the element using element ID.

In Your HTML you have the ID `new-todo` your your element So you can use like :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("new-todo")).sendKeys("value");
```

Still you are looking for that element to locate using CSSSelector then use :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#new-todo")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

OR Using Class name for that tag :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

> How do I bypass these ng-view tags

You can consider the parent tag and no need to include that tag (you want to skip) in your path like :

```
aside.learn input#new-todo
```

Here I've consider parent tag i.e. `aside` and locate the `input` inside that

Comment: I had already tried with id selectors which didn't work. 
In node, there is no method 'cssSelector' for webdriver.by  <http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_By.html> 
Tried all the css paths you mentioned in your answer but unfortunately, nothing worked.
    trace: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="new-todo"]"}

    version info: chrome 58.0
    chrome driver: 2.24

Comment: No, there is no iframe tag in the webpage.

Comment: in node there is `driver.findElement(By.css('.autocomplete'))` `css` instead of `cssSelector`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145598/discussion-between-trimantra-software-solution-and-pritam).

Comment: added a wait before sendKeys and it worked with By.css method!
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("<css path>")));

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you can use dynamic Xpath

For your case you can use following xpath:

```
//input[@placeholder='Intended web element for which css path is needed']
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Need to put wait before the findElement method otherwise this fails. Valid answer though.